# Magento 1.8: Change Price via Textbox in frontend

Tags: magento, updates, frontend, product

I'm trying too change the Product Price in Magento 1.8 via Frontend Textbox. 
For example a customer can change the Price from 100 € to 105 € only by using the textbox near to the Price.

What i have done so far:

Create textfild in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/produkt/view.phtml -it works

```
<form action='http://site.de/Aufschlag/AufschlagTill/save' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='add product id here' />
  <input type='text' name='price' />
  <input type='submit' value='submit' />
 </form>
```

Create a modul named "Aufschlag"
app/code/local/Aufschlag/AufschlagTill/Controllers - contains the savepriceController.php

```
 <?php 
 class Aufschlag_AufschlagTill_savepriceController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{ public function saveAction(){
$websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

$product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
// need to validate price here
$price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)
if($product->getId()){
    $product->setPrice($price)->save();
}
}
?>
```

app/code/local/Aufschlag/AufschlagTil/etc - contains the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <aufschlag_aufschlagtill>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </aufschlag_aufschlagtill>
</modules>
     <frontend>
    <routers>
        <aufschlag_aufschlagtill>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Aufschlag_AufschlagTill</module>
                <frontName>AufschlagTill</frontName>
            </args>
        </aufschlag_aufschlagtill>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
```

app/etc/modules/Aufschlag_AufschlagTill.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
     <modules>
            <Aufschlag_AufschlagTill>
                    <active>true</active>
                    <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Aufschlag_AufschlagTill>
     </modules>
</config>
```

Is this the right way to solve the Problem or is there a better solution to get a fild which edits the price in frondend?!?

Comment: thats the way to do it properly. edit price on frontend though? I'm intrigued?

Comment: Problem is that the result is an empty white page without function.